# .NET including class library database (and other resources) with windows app deployment

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express, class-library

I have a class library that attaches itself a tiny SQL Server database that resides in its Data Directory. When i'm using this class library with another windows application i see that once i compile my code, the database files get copied to the bin folder of my windows app project. However when i publish the windows app,install, and run it, i get the error 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\Data..\DB.mdf failed.' Obviously this folder doesn't have the mdf files.

I guess this won't be a problem if i just add the database files to my windows application project. But surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include an SQL script for creating the database into your "installation/run first time routine".

I guess that you've already stated that having a form of SQL Server is an installtion prerequisite.

For the data files I would recommend that you use a variable connection string for accessing your database. That way you can change the installation routine to include asking the user where they wish to have the data files installed and save that as part of your connection string to the app.config file.

Conversely you could also use the users selection of where to install the app to override the relative path stored for the database within your code (using the same connection string variable as mentioned above).